# What can I do if celery sometimes forgets task?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have problem with latest version of celery (3.0.19).
I have very simple task:

```
@celery.task()
def last_uid():
    return 100
```

i execute it by

```
uid = last_uid.apply_async(None, queue='base_s1').get(timeout=4)
```

everything seems to work, but celery sometimes lost this task. This is celery log - http://pastebin.com/4ePbiFdf

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed name of the queue from base_s1 to root_s1 and everything works now..